# Html php email form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Hello I am trying to add a html email form to my website but cannot get it to work. The following is the code I currently have but when I try the form I don't receive an email.

```
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    Your name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your message:<br> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
    </form> 
    <?php 
    }  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{ 
$name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
$email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
    echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
    } 
else{         
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
        mail("****************", $subject, $message, $from); 
        echo "Email sent!"; 
        } 
    }   
?>
```

Comment: We need details! What doesn't work?  Do you get an error?  If so, what is the error?

Comment: Does it show the error message, or any other messages?

Comment: Where is your webserver located? A development server on your own computer. Or on webhosting? Because your smtp settings and port forwards have to be correctly configured if you are using your own webserver locally.

Comment: I used domain monster as my host

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

It will save you a lot of trouble and there are plenty of guides, with freely available default configs where all you need to do is modify the contents, sender and recipient of the email.

Answer (score 1):

first - use $_POST, not $_REQUEST;
second - is there right settings on your server? maybe there is no mail support;
and the last - 4th argument of mail function is not "from", it's headers where you can also set mime-type and others..

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: I am using domainmonster as my webhost if that makes any difference?

Comment: ask technical support, is there mail support on your hosting

Answer (score 0):

the error is in this line :

```
mail("****************", $subject, $message, $from);
```

replace the asterisks with your email

Comment: Seems stack overflow has replaced my email address with *****

Answer (score 0):

mail function returns boolean, check whether it is sending or not sending.
Change your mail code like below and try to know whats happening.

`

```
if (mail("himmerz@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from)) {
echo 'send';
} else {
echo 'not send';
}
```

`

Comment: After pressing submit i get the following printed "sendEmail sent!" However I still receive no email

Comment: check also whether the mail is in spam folder or may be in queue

Answer (score 0):

```
mail("****************", $subject, $message, $from);
```

change to:

```
mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);
```